# Label for checkbox is not showing as it should

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to see my checkbox label but it is not showing - when I use the console I can se that the div is created but the checkbox label is not showing on the screen. What am I missing here?

Thanks for the help.

```js
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: true,
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind();
  }
  onChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    });
    console.log(this.state.checked)
  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = {
        `checkbox ${this.props.color}`
      }
      onClick = {
        this.onChange
      } >
      <
      div > {
        this.state.checked &&
        <
        span className = "checkbox-box-mark" >
        <
        svg viewBox = "0 0 64 64"
        xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" > < path d = "M21.33,57.82,0,36.53l5.87-5.87L21.33,46.09,58.13,9.36,64,15.23,21.33,57.82" / > < /svg> <
        /span>
      } <
      /div>    <
      div className = "checkbox-label" > checkbox < /div>  <
      /div>     
    )
  }
}
export default Checkbox
```

Comment: Hey, I can see the checkbox label. check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bh7mnfqt/). Can you explain what are you expecting

Comment: Hi @anu, thanks for the response. My goal is to have the label next to the checkbox and for the label to keep its position whether or not the checkbox is been clicked or not, on my local server the label is positioned below the checkbox and when I click (check) the checkbox for my svg to show the label moves again. I want it to stay in position. I have included my css in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bfahydts/